# Prettier Angular html parser bad inline tag formatting

Tags: prettier

I get this:

```
<div class="text">
  Sorry, we couldn’t find an account for <b>{{ phoneInput }}</b
  >, let's create one:
</div>
```

But if I switch to html parser, I get this which is much better:

```
<div class="text">
  Sorry, we couldn’t find an account for <b>{{ phoneInput }}</b>, let's create
  one:
</div>
```

Even if the line was longer, it should be broken down the new lines differently. The code `<b>{{ phoneInput }}</b>`, should be treated as a single unit, so if line length was the issue, I'd expect this:

```
<div class="text">
  Sorry, we couldn’t find an account for 
  <b>{{ phoneInput }}</b>, let's create one:
</div>
```

am I missing something here?

Note: This is NOT related to sensitive whitespace, I'm aware of that issue. The expected result perserves that.

Answer (score 0):

Because Prettier saves the original text. Your formatted HTML code contains extra spaces that are not in the original code.

You can check `--html-whitespace-sensitivity` and read more about whitespace-sensitive formatting here: https://prettier.io/blog/2018/11/07/1.15.0.html#whitespace-sensitive-formatting

Comment: I'm aware of white space sensitivity, but the html prettier parser works fine, while the angular parser doesn't